# Measure speaker volume by recording playing sound with microphone

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I want to measure a system's speaker volume by playing a sound and listening for it on a local microphone at the same time. This is for a specific application. The exact recorded sound is not as important as differentiating between the microphone volume recorded before the sound is played and while it is playing.

The idea is to warn the user if speakers are turned off or too low. How can I record a sound while playing it and determine a difference in volume? Are there are any managed libraries to do this?

---

**Update:** Found a [good related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191613/managed-access-to-microphone-input-and-system-volume).

Comment: Microphones don't generally measure absolute volume - they would have to be calibrated (or be in a known environment). For example, if you point your mic at a speaker, you will read a particular level. If you turn the speaker around, you will read a lower level. Same thing if the speaker is moved closer or farther from the mic.

Comment: If the related question you found solved your problem, it'll be nice if you posted it as an answer and checked it as the correct answer (so this post could be removed from the unanswered questions list)

Comment: @Seth: I realise this. I am only interested in measuring a relative volume difference before and during playback, not an absolute volume.

Comment: @Neowizard: the related question does not provide a straight-forward solution for my question, but points me in the right direction. I will post an answer when I have worked up a good solution.

Comment: yes,related question is good. its quite old now(for me). I used propably Naudio demo app(I remember those 2 green level bars) or other app from some tutorial, but I dont remember any details. It was quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

Take this:

http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/

and use waveIn managed wrapper.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712636(VS.85).aspx

Of course, you'll need some calibration there...

Comment: First link is dead. I just need to check if the microphone is being used or not. Could you please help?